# Blog post : Remove comma between Tag names

Tags: tags

I have given background colors to the blog post Tag names. No, I do not need the "," between the tag names. how can I remove it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your site uses [`the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_tags/) to display the list of tags with a link to each tag.

This function by default uses a comma as a separator. This can be changed via the second parameter of that function:

```
the_tags( null, '' );
```

The first parameter is the text before the list ("Tags: "), the second parameter the separator (which is now changed to an empty string).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @swissspidy Where shall i insert the above code?

Comment: @mazharkhan you need to search for `the_tags(` in your theme and replace the code there. If it's a theme you downloaded/purchased from somewhere you might consider creating a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead. Let's say you find `the_tags(` in file `home.php`, then you can copy that file to your child theme and do the replacement there.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do that and come back! Really appreciate your detailed response.

Comment: there are so many .php files in Dashboard -> Apperance -> Editor. 

Is there anyway I can easily find this `the_tags()` code? 

I have created child theme. Just dont know where to find this code in those php files.

Thank You

Comment: i found the code in functions.php file 

   `// Render tags.
   if ( $settings['post_meta_tags'] ) {
    ob_start();
    the_tags( '' );
    $tags = ob_get_clean();

    if ( $tags ) {
     /* translators: The tags list. */
     $metadata .= '<span class="meta-tags">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Tags: %s', 'Avada' ), $tags ) . '</span><span class="fusion-inline-sep">|</span>';
    }
   }`

Comment: They suggested that this can be done by adding filter. 

`add_filter( 'the_tags', 'remove_default_comma', 20, 5 );
function remove_default_comma( string $tag_list, string $before, string $sep, string $after, int $id ) {
 return get_the_term_list( $id, 'post_tag', $before, '', $after );
}`

Comment: but its not working its showing some error 

`Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 17 of file wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.`

Argument 1 passed to remove_default_comma() must be an instance of string, string given